# Windows 7 to Windows 10 desktop change causes SSIS Error: cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types

Tags: oracle, ssis, windows-7, windows-10

I am required to switch from an old virtual desktop Windows 7 to a new Windows 10 desktop, requiring all new software installs. I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 in both environments. I have overcome my initial Oracle data provider configuration issues, but now every old package I open in the new environment has the same problem. On the dataflow tasks ORACLE -> SQL Server, ssis message: column “exampleColumn” cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types. These are NEW error messages,  I can still open on the Windows 7 desktop and run them fine but on this new Windows 10 box all errors.  This is on existing packages, NOT the same problem everyone else is having when I do Google searches. Have I missed installing something? [Windows07-works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAVw1.jpg)[Windows10-NotWorking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gvoq.jpg)

Comment: Did you migrate source oracle from win7 to win10 too?

Comment: No ORACLE server is the same, I can even preview the data, even on the Windows 10 version, so I know the basic ORACLE stuff is fixed, as in tns names etc. but the error is still there...both Oracle source and SQL Server Target databases are the same external separate boxes.

Comment: we can fix this issue by using `derived column` and converting data. Though I would like to know root cause. Clearly oracle's char has been changed. That's why this issue is arriving. I will try to dig it deeper.